# using $sce.trustAsResourceUrl

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to work with a directive but i get an error. I found out that i should wrap the template url around $sce.trustAsResourceUrl, however, how should i do that correctly.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('myPhotos', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {},
      controller: function($scope) {
        var photos = $scope.photos = []; 
        $scope.select = function(photo) {
          angular.forEach(photos, function(photo) {
            photo.selected = false;
          });
          photo.selected = true;
        };
        this.addPhoto = function(photo) {
          photos.push(photo);
        };
      },
      templateUrl: 'file:///home/mihaly/meanbook/CH24/my_photos.html'
    };
  })
  .directive('myPhoto', function() {
    return {
      require: '^myPhotos',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: { title: '@'},
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, photosControl) {
        photosControl.addPhoto(scope);
      },
      template: '<div ng-show="selected" ng-transclude></div>'
    };
  });
```

Comment: Error: [$sce:insecurl] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/$sce/insecurl?p0=file%3A%2F%2F%2Fhome%2Fmihaly%2Fmeanbook%2FCH24%2Fmy_photos.html

Comment: try giving templateUrl relative to js file not the file: path. Also, you may wanna try it running on server if you are not as  loading template is an ajax call.

Comment: Unfortunateley still not working.. I run the file using http-server in node...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use $sce to use templateUrl in directive, just use the path to your html template not as a file://

```
templateUrl: '../my_photos.html'
```